# When are $3$ vectors associative in triple cross products?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question I am trying to show under what conditions

$$\vec{A}\times(\vec{B}\times\vec{C}) = (\vec{A}\times\vec{B})\times\vec{C}.$$

I have found that right-hand side of the above equation is equal to

\begin{align}
(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})\times\vec{C}
&=-\vec{C}\times(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})\\
&= \vec{C}\times(\vec{B}\times\vec{A}).
\end{align}

This is similar to the left-hand side of the original equation.

The conclusion I arrived at was, in order for the equality to be true, either $\vec{A}, \vec{B}$ or $\vec{C}$ have to be zero, or $\vec{A}$ must be equal to $\vec{C}$.

Is this correct? If not, or if I am missing anything, please let me know.

Comment: What do you think happens when $\vec A = \lambda \vec C$ for some scalar $\lambda$?

Comment: I think that since multiplication by scalar would be distributive, it would also be an additional condition for equality. Is that correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. The reason is that the [cross product is anti-commutative.](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cross_Product_is_Anticommutative) Therefore, the only situations wherein you will find the desired properties are when one of the vectors is zero, or when $A \propto C$

To prove this, note that $A\times (B\times C) = (A\cdot C)B-(A\cdot B)C$ and likewise $(A\times B)\times C = -(C\cdot B)A+(C\cdot A)B$

Assume the two are equal, and note that the dot product commutes, and we find

$$ (A\cdot B) C = (C\cdot B) A $$

Then, $$\frac{A}{A\cdot B} = \frac{C}{C \cdot B} \implies C = kA.$$

So $C$ is some scalar multiple of $A$.

Comment: Thanks. I have a few quick followup questions.

1) Is there any way to derive the AX(BXC) = BAC-CAB or is it just a shortcut that cuts down on tedious algebraic manipulation?
2) Where does the $k$ come from at the very end, that says that another possible solution is that $C$ is a scalar multiple of $A$ and not just equal?

Comment: @achacttn Since $k = \frac{A\cdot B}{C\cdot B}$. The dot product is just a scalar number, so the ratio of dot products is a scalar number. In this case, we're looking for conditions of equality; $A,B,C$ aren't variables, so there's nothing lost by saying $C = \frac{A\cdot B}{C\cdot B} A$. The triple product relation I used can be found by doing out the algebra; it's called the "triple product expansion", see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product

Comment: @Emily I think there's another possibility when the triple product is associative: when the vector $B$ is orthogonal to both $A$ and $C$. In your prove you assumed that $A\cdot B$ and $C\cdot B$ are both non-zero; which might not be the case.